# batch waiting until script finishes

Tags: php, python, windows, batch-file

I have the following batch file called `controller.bat`:

```
BCDEDIT /bootsequence {db3add28-ed9f-11e2-be67-1c6f65c20c01}
ECHO "running on WIN8_X86_NES..."
python C:\performance\test_1.py
php C:\performance\test_2.php
ECHO "Waiting for 3 minutes before restarting..."
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000 > nul
SHUTDOWN /r /t 00
```

I execute these two `.py` and `.php` test scripts, which execute some performance tests ... after it's done, I want to restart the machine ... However, I want to make sure that both scripts end, otherwise I may run the risk to have the tests started and then the machine restart.
How do I make sure that the batch script awaits till both scripts are finished before proceeding?
Will `call` do it?

Comment: Did you try `call` and see?

Comment: @martineau I did not ... should I do: `call python C:\performance\test_1.py`?

Comment: I'd put a `start /wait python C:\performance\test_1.py` and similar for the php script. Not sure about the `ping` and `shutdown` commands.

Comment: @martineau could you post your idea as an answer?

Comment: Nah, that's OK. Anyway, for a 3 minute pause you need a `-w 180000` on the `ping` -- the timeout's in milliseconds.

Comment: Actually you don't even need the `ping` -- just use `shutdown /r /t 180`.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use `call` or `start /wait`. Both will work as they start the .py and .php file as part of the batch file. So it will wiat for them to completely execute. Though you should note starting them  as an operable program should work.

Mona

Comment: I believe call is for calling one _batch_ program from another without stopping the parent batch program -- at least that's what the documentation says.